# FFMPEG set a upper limit to bitrate only a a interval of video

Tags: video, ffmpeg

How i can define a variable bitrate from 500k to 1024k between 0~1min30, between 1min30~3min up it to 2048 to 4096 and from 3min until end down it to 500~1024 again?